# Passing thread level local variable from one class to another

Tags: java, multithreading

Below is the scenario.

```
public class A{
   private final B b;

   public A(){
     this.b = new B();
     this.c = new C();
   }

   public void setValue(){
      this.b.value("HELLO WORLD")
      this.c.print();
   }
}
```

Setting "Hello World" to text

```
public class B{
    public volatile String text;
    public B(){
        this.text = "";
    }
    public void value(String t){
        this.text = t;
    }
}
```

unable to get "Hello World". its coming back as ""

```
public class C{
    private final B b;
    public B(){
        this.b = new B;
    }
    public void print(){
        System.out.println(this.b.text);
    }
}
```

Any Help will be appreciated. I need a solution to pass value to one class to another

Comment: Class C never calls B.value(). The text is never set. Is an instance of A running as a separate thread? If so, A has its own copy of B, the B used in C is different.

Comment: I want to get the value which is set by class A. all is running in same thread

Comment: I don't see any instantiations of class A. Where is A.setValue called?

Comment: There are several problems.  As [Anand Tiwari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62269942/3135317) correctly pointed out, your constructor is overwriting the value. Q: Do you want B.text to be class-wide?  If so, declare it `static String text;`.  Q: Or do you want it to be per-object (each class instance has it's own value for 'text").  SUGGESTION: In either case, please make "text" private, and use standard getters/setters: `public void setText(String text)`, `public string getText()`.

Comment: You create 2 instances of `B` but only set the string in one of them. `volatile` doesn't mean thread-local

Comment: Why does your class B extend the Thread class? There's nowhere in your example that uses an instance of B _as_ a thread.

Comment: @SolomonSlow - Sorry that was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

I think the assignment inside the constructor of B is causing you the problem. As you have made text volatile so every time you create an instance of B, the value of text is overwritten by "" and then all thread will read this updated value. Just make text variable static and then you can get the "Hello World" in class C.

Comment: The problem he is facing has nothing to do with marking the field `volatile`

Comment: I never said that volatile field is the problem I just pointed out that assignment in B will change the value of volatile field any how and every time. So he has to get rid of that assignment to get desired value.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, have to send the reference of B to C from A

```
public class A{
   private final B b;
   private final C c;

   public A(){
     this.b = new B();
     this.c = new C (this.b);
   }

   public void setValue(){
      this.b.value("HELLO WORLD");
      this.c.print();
   }
}


public class B{
    public volatile String text;
    public B(){
        this.text = "";
    }
    public void value(String t){
        this.text = t;
    }
}


public class C{
    private final B b;
    public C(B b){
        this.b = b;
    }
    public void print(){
        System.out.println(this.b.text);
    }
}
```